# How can I generate a full body avatar (model) from a user's profile photo or measurements in Next.js or React.js?

Tags: model-view-controller, model, avatar, 3d-model, avatar-generation

I'm looking for an open-source API that can generate a full-body avatar based on a photo of a user. I'd like to explore the possibility of integrating this functionality into a project I'm working on. Could you please provide me with more information on how I can access the API documentation for free? Any guidance on the best practices for using this type of API would also be greatly appreciated.